# Visual.Studio Xamarin.Android ошибка компиляции

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

хочу создать проект под минимальную версию 4.0.3.
В настройках выбрал минимальную версию и целевую версию 4.0.3 и скомпилировать с помощью версии 4.0.3
Попытался скомпилировать, выдает предупреждения

```
Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2.           
Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2.   
Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2.   
Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2.   
Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 25.4.0.2.
```

Попытался через NuGet установить именно версии 23.3.0, не дало установить:

```
Идет восстановление пакетов для D:\Учеба\Диплом\app\App1\App1\App1\App1.csproj...
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0 несовместим с netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0 поддерживает: monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3)
Идет восстановление пакетов для D:\Учеба\Диплом\app\App1\App1\App1.Android\App1.Android.csproj...
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2.
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2.
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 25.4.0.2.
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2.
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
Сбой при восстановлении пакета. Откат изменений пакета для «App1».
Прошло времени: 00:00:00.1240403
========== Готово ==========
```

Судя по 2 строчке, нужно NET.STANDART понижать.
Понизил до версии 1.0 (самая меньшая)
Попытался также понизить до версии 23.3.0 для любой из библиотек:

```
Идет восстановление пакетов для D:\Учеба\Диплом\app\App1\App1\App1\App1.csproj...
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 несовместим с netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 поддерживает: monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3)
Идет восстановление пакетов для D:\Учеба\Диплом\app\App1\App1\App1.iOS\App1.iOS.csproj...
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 несовместим с xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 поддерживает: monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 несовместим с xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 поддерживает: monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 несовместим с xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 поддерживает: monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 несовместим с xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0 поддерживает: monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3)
Идет восстановление пакетов для D:\Учеба\Диплом\app\App1\App1\App1.Android\App1.Android.csproj...
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2.
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2.
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2.
NU1608: Версия обнаруженного пакета нарушает ограничение зависимости: Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.280555 требуется Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0), но в результате разрешения получена версия Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2.
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
NU1202: Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2 несовместим с monoandroid403 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3). Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2 поддерживает: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
Сбой при восстановлении пакета. Откат изменений пакета для «App1».
Прошло времени: 00:00:00.4063779
========== Готово ==========
```

Судя по 2 строчке даже netStandart 1.0 не совместим. Куда ниже то?
Помогите разобраться в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

судя по второй строчке надо посмотреть что за зависимости у Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0.(там пишется минимальная версия других компонентов) особенно интересно, чего это Android проект стал типом  standard а не mono android.
4 строчка последнего вывода ошибки вообще говорит, что у вас там еще и iOS висит.

Создайте новый проект из готового шаблона Visual Studio. Установите зависимости на api 15 в android и запустите.